# MATLAB: How do you insert a line of text at the beginning of a file?

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files

I have a file full of ascii data.  How would I append a string to the first line of the file? I cannot find that sort of functionality using fopen (it seems to only append at the end and nothing else.)

Comment: What operating system are you running MATLAB on?

Comment: Windows 32x, unfortunately.  If this was Linux it'd be a complete non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1:

I would suggest [calling some system commands from within MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/system.html). One possibility on Windows is to write your new line of text to its own file and then use the [DOS **for** command](http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm) to [concatenate the two files](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-concatenate-multiple-text-files-in-windows/). Here's what the call would look like in MATLAB:

```
!for %f in ("file1.txt", "file2.txt") do type "%f" >> "new.txt"
```

I used the [`!` (bang) operator](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/specialcharacters.html) to invoke the command from within MATLAB. The command above sequentially pipes the contents of "file1.txt" and "file2.txt" to the file "new.txt". Keep in mind that you will probably have to end the first file with a new line character to get things to append correctly.

Another alternative to the above command would be:

```
!for %f in ("file2.txt") do type "%f" >> "file1.txt"
```

which appends the contents of "file2.txt" to "file1.txt", resulting in "file1.txt" containing the concatenated text instead of creating a new file.

If you have your file names in strings, you can create the command as a string and use the [SYSTEM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) command instead of the `!` operator. For example:

```
a = 'file1.txt';
b = 'file2.txt';
system(['for %f in ("' b '") do type "%f" >> "' a '"']);
```

### Option 2:

One MATLAB only solution, in addition to [Amro's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638960/matlab-how-do-you-insert-a-line-of-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file/1639423#1639423), is:

```
dlmwrite('file.txt',['first line' 13 10 fileread('file.txt')],'delimiter','');
```

This uses [FILEREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fileread.html) to read the text file contents into a string, concatenates the new line you want to add (along with the [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a carriage return and a line feed/new line), then overwrites the original file using [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html).

I get the feeling Option #1 might perform faster than this pure MATLAB solution for huge text files, but I don't know that for sure. ;)

Comment: Is there any way to use MATLAB variables for the filenames in the dos command?

Comment: @temp2290: I added a discussion of that to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

The following is a pure MATLAB solution:

```
% write first line
dlmwrite('output.txt', 'string 1st line', 'delimiter', '')
% append rest of file
dlmwrite('output.txt', fileread('input.txt'), '-append', 'delimiter', '')
% overwrite on original file
movefile('output.txt', 'input.txt')
```

Comment: +1: This fits with what I was thinking of for option #2, but I had a slightly different take on how to do it. I'll post for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `frewind(fid)` function to take the pointer to the beginning of the file?

I had a similar requirement and tried `frewind()` followed by the necessary `fprintf()` statement.

But, warning: It will overwrite on whichever is the 1st line. Since in my case, I was the one writing the file, I put a dummy data at the starting of the file and then at the end, let that be overwritten after the operations specified above.

BTW, even I am facing one problem with this solution, that, depending on the length(/size) of the dummy data and actual data, the program either leaves part of the dummy data on the same line, or bring my new data to the 2nd line..
Any tip in this regards is highly appreciated.