# matlab: move last line of text file to top

Tags: matlab, text-files, line

I'm not well versed in Matlab.
I'm working with data composed of alphanumerics and symbols.
I want to move the bottom line to the very top of the file.
I've looked into other methods that use fseek and such, but those have confused me and were using ultra specific file characteristics. 
Is there a general way to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no built-in function for this. But there's an easy way I think with the following steps:

1. Read the whole file [freadf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html).
2. Move the last line in the matrix two the first.
3. And write back to the file [fwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

For an alphanumeric file the simplest easily understandable approach would be to read the file completely, save the lines in a string cell array and write it in an order which fits you.  These lines should solve your problem here.

```
readfin = fopen('myfile.txt','r');
writefin = fopen('modifiedfile.txt', 'w');
lineno = 1;

% Get all lines one by one and save them
while(~feof(readfin))
    newline{lineno} = fgetl(readfin); 
    lineno = lineno + 1;
end

% Write first line
fprintf(writefin, '%s', newline{end});

% Write the rest of the lines one by one
for lineno=1:(length(newline)-1)
    fprintf(writefin,'\n');
    fprintf(writefin, '%s', newline{lineno});
end

fclose(readfin);
fclose(writefin);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this from this answer:
[MATLAB: How do you insert a line of text at the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638960/matlab-how-do-you-insert-a-line-of-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file)

```
fid = fopen(filepath);

while 1
    line = fgetl(fid);

    if ~ischar(line)
        break;
    end

    pline = line;

end
fclose(fid);

dlmwrite(filepath,[pline 13 10 fileread(filepath)],'delimiter','');
```